# Azure TopicClient.Send() never sends a message and it hangs

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

I am attempting to follow a [Windows Azure tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/) to send a message to a topic on Microsoft's Azure service bus.  I have created the namespace and the topic.   I then set up ACS and grabbed my connection string.   My connection string allows Manage, Listen, Send.  When I execute my code, the Send(message) just hangs.  It never times-out nor does it continue.  The CPU is not maxed and I can break out of the code and close the program.  No message arrives in Azure.  When I watch my network traffic in fiddler, it looks to me like it is never finishing the authentication negotiations.  I see a post to my namespace .servicebus.windows.net that returns a 201 then a post and a get at an IP address that belongs to Azure service bus with a /$servicebus/webstring/{guid}.  Neither of these web request ever get a response back from the server.  Here is my code.  It stops running on client.Send(message);

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];
        var client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "clients");
        Console.WriteLine(client.IsClosed);

        var message = new BrokeredMessage("Test message.") {TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)};
        client.Send(message);

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Any ideas on how to get this code to post a message to Azure service bus?

Comment: When you Debug the code.. that is if you are debugging the code what value do you have for connectionString after this line
`string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];`

Comment: I still have the connection string as loaded from my configuration manager.  When I inspect the client, the client.address has the correct URI.

Comment: try wrapping a try catch{} around the client.Send(message); and see if it throws any errors

Comment: I assume you're waiting more than 15 minutes for it to time out?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, I've waited up to an hour.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I tried the try/catch and received no error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing this behavior when using this code and it appears to be linked to the ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode you have set.  If you comment that out it goes through. That mode isn't mentioned in the tutorial.  The default the mode is Auto and it detects if it can send via TCP first.

With that said, I'd like to suggest you use the following code instead:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];

MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
MessageSender testQueue = factory.CreateMessageSender("TestTopic");

BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage("Test message ");
testQueue.Send(message);
```

One of the benefits of using the MessageSender instead of  the TopicClient or QueueClient directly is that your code doesn't care if the destination is a Topic or a Queue.  If you later needed to change from one to another your code here wouldn't have to change.  Likewise, using a MessageReceiver  on the consuming code is better as well.

Comment: I took the ServiceBusEnviroment.SystemConnectivityMode out and I get an exception trying to communicate over TCP port 9354.  The target machine actively refuses the connection.  This would be because of my company's outbound firewall rules.  I cannot get those changed.  This must work over ports 80/443.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see that issue, I can post the message on a topic with same code and receive it via a subscription as well. The SAS key I use is generated on Topic itself. My the issue you had was temporary issue? [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be our corporate firewall.  It is actively refusing connections on unknown ports (9354) instead of passively.  This seems to keep the Microsoft library for Azure from auto-detecting the connection and switching to https.  It appears that with an active refusal of the connection at 9354 an exception get thrown in the library instead of trying http.  Likewise, if I set the mode to just Http, it hangs, but when I am outside the corporate firewall it does not hang.  It would be nice if this library worked with an active refusal on port 9354.